# Expectation of inverse chi-square random variable (Efron, 2010)

Tags: bayesian, empirical-bayes

Let $z_i|\mu\sim N(\mu,1)$ and $\mu\sim N(B,A)$ for $i=1,\dots,N$, the implication is that $z_i|B\sim N(B,A+1)$.

Define $S=\|\textbf{z}\|^2$, and let $B=0$, then  $S\sim(A+1)\chi^2_N$ since $\|\textbf{z}\|^2/(A+1)\sim \chi^2_N$.

**Question:** How do I show that: 
$$E\Big\{\frac{N-2}{S}\Big\}=\frac{1}{A+1}?$$

I do not see how this is possible since:

$E(S)=(A+1)N$ and $\frac{1}{A+1}=E\Big\{\frac{N}{S}\Big\}$.

I do not know where the $N-2$ is coming from.

Can anybody help?

**Context:** $\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$This question originates from page 4 of Efron's book (*Large Scale Inference, Empirical Bayes methods for estimation, Testing and Prediction*).

Answer (score 4):

For any chisquare random variable with $\nu > 2$ degrees of freedom, $X\sim \chi^2_\nu$, the expected value of the inverse variable is
$$E\left(\frac{1}{X}\right)=\frac{1}{\nu-2}$$
See for example the [Wikipedia article on the inverse chisquare distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-chi-squared_distribution)

The result you ask about follows immediately.